# How to avoid taking bed bugs along with the luggage

Tags: sleeping, bed-bugs

Today me and my girlfriend faced a problem while staying in a airbnb rented room in barcelona - we woke up with bed bug bites all over our bodies. We've instantly decided to move out of this place. The thing is we're staying in Spain for two more weeks, so our great concern is not to take the bugs along with us in our suitcases - what's the best way to prevent that?

Comment: My Wife always turns on her hair dryer on full heat and speed on the luggage from almost no distance and scans around the whole luggage making sure no inch is left untreated

Comment: Visit a laundry service in between?

Comment: @HankyPanky 's comment is the right direction. Not sure if a hair dryer will get hot enough, but if you can run *all* of your clothes through a high-heat dry cycle and heat treat your luggage (especially any crevices/seams) above about 70C/160F you should be ok. Just make sure the clothing you are wearing at the time is not infested. Good luck! (Voice of experience here. :( ) (As an aside, as near as we can tell we picked up the bugs in our luggage during transit from SE Asia to N. America by our suitcases just being next to infested luggage.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe go to a laundry shop and wash your clothes in high heat. And expose your luggage out the sun for a time. Bed bugs do not usually hang out on your hair or skin or clothes when you are out and about.
https://www.bedbugsupply.com/can-bed-bugs-live-in-hair-or-on-body.html

Or if you cannot find a laundry shop, wash your clothes when you get home and place your luggage out of your house for at least a day.